# Sorting table by column

Tags: javascript, php, sorting, html-table

I'm looking for a way to sort an HTML table; I've never had to do this before, so I don't know what the best way to do so is; in particular, I'm looking for something that's fast, and easy to set up and manage later on.  Does anyone know of a jQuery or JavaScript to do so?

Comment: It can be done just with JavaScript: Google is your friend in this matter. Or you can use a library: jQuery has some plugins that do it pretty well with minimal coding needed from you.

Comment: A very beautiful way of creating HTML tables with sorting column feature. Not only sort but also you can do many more interactive things with an HTML table. Just [refer this article](http://www.funbutlearn.com/2013/04/create-interactive-html-tables-with.html) to know more. I think you will really get your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't get far using JS' sort(). I tend to use the TableSorter plugin for jQuery, which is  fairly easy to get going, and even easier if you've already got jQuery loaded.

It can automatically pick up how to sort certain data (strings, ints, etc), but for more complex data (e.g. unusually formatted dates), you may need to write a little extra code to help it along. More info at: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

I think it's also possible to style the sorted tables nicely - the ones on tablesorter.com are rather drab...

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from jquery - javascript which by the way can be disabled by any smart web user,  you can do it hardcore by customized SQL strings which are called by a link in the header that calls to sort action.  When the sort header is clicked,  the page is redirected to itself with an specific call to invoke the customized SQL query which has a different `order by ...` syntax.
This is a `<noscript>` alternative that I recommend to keep in mind after implementing the useful and rich jquery alternatives.  This way the majority of your users will be pleased with a jquery UX,  but the occasional user script concerned,  also can enjoy the sorting capabilities.  Keep in mind that this method costs more to the server than jquery,  so my recommendation is to use both.